# Nuxt removes universal selectors from css after deployment

Tags: css, vue.js, nuxt.js

Inside my index.vue page I have the following in the styling:

```
<style lang="scss">
    *:where(:not(iframe, canvas, img, svg, video):not(svg *, symbol *)) {
      all: unset;
      display: revert;
    }
    
    *,
    *::before,
    *::after {
      box-sizing: border-box;
    }
</style>
```

Locally this works fine, but doesn't work after deploying on vercel. When inspecting the source on this version I can see that the * selectors have been removed:

```
:where(:not(iframe):not(canvas):not(img):not(svg):not(video):not(svg*):not(symbol*)){all:unset;display:revert}*,:after,:before{box-sizing:border-box}
```

The same thing happens regardless of how it's imported, whether by importing a separate file in the config, or importing a file inside the style tags.

Comment: Does it work if you build locally too? Did you tried on Netlify?

Comment: Just tried it with yarn build and the same problem now happens locally. Seems to be a problem with that build process.

Comment: You're using static no? It should be `yarn generate`.